# What is the actual width of a Panaracer Pasela tire?

Tags: tire

Not unlike other brands, I've heard that older Panaracer Pasela tires ran slim when compared to their advertised width, probably [a marketing ploy to get the weight down for its size](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#dishonest) - but I've also heard and read (on the internets..) that recent production has changed such that the widths are wider, more true to spec.

The cool thing about the Paselas is that they come in so many sizes.  That's also the bad thing - none of the local bike shops carry them.  I'm trying to determine the widest tire I can fit in my bike.  Anyone out there with Paselas on your bike, can you report the width of the tire at its widest point, along with the spec'd width?  Even better would be someone with the [Pasela TG 700c x 28](http://www.velofred.com/product_info_p.php?products_id=519&) - the size I'm aiming for - that would more than awesome.

Answer (score 4):

My plain black Pasela 700X32C tire measures only about 29mm on a fairly standard road rim. Had it a couple of years, so it may be older production.

Comment: It is now 2023, and a new 32-622 Pasela measures 29mm on narrow (standard by 2011 standards) rim.

Answer (score 3):

I just got an email from Harris Cyclery, and they said the plain Paselas (no Tour Guard etc.) run "pretty true to width".  Didn't get any measurements from them, though, and i don't have any Paselas myself.  I use 28 mm Panaracer Rolly Poly tires, and will soon be getting a set of 28 mm Grand Bois Cerf.

Would be nice to have a webpage of true width measurements of various popular tires on various popular rims.

Answer (score 1):

I'm decidedly a non-expert, but the following opinion is based on my experience with tires for other types of vehicles.

One thing that might be a factor in determining the correct tire width (for any tire) is the rim width.  To match the tire width specified by manufacturer you have to have rims with the same width as the reference rim they use.  If your rim is wider, then the tire will inflate slightly wider (the side walls will bulge out further, and the contact patch will widen as well), a narrower rim gives you a narrower tire.

To get a feel for how this works, in the extreme (for snow bikes), [Surly Large Marge rims](http://surlybikes.com/parts/large_marge/) are 65mm wide and are typically used with [Surly Endomorph tires](http://surlybikes.com/parts/endomorph_tire/) that are 3.7" wide, but another company, Chain Reaction Cycles sells a [100mm wide rim](http://www.chainreactioncycles.us/Flattop%20Rim.html) for use with the same tires.  The reason for the added width is because it adds volume to the tire and actually makes the contact patch wider, a useful benefit when you are trying to float over snow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you're right, rim width is important but I think my wheels will fit the tires without a problem.  What concerns me is tread clearance in my road bike's center pull brakes. I'm trying to find the wides tire I can fit without having to change out my brakes to something like cantilevers.

Comment: @sk606 the rim width influences the width and height of your tyre. The difference between a 13 mm and a 20 mm rim (both typical on road bikes) may be enough for the tyre to clear or foul, respectively, the frame.